# How to generate and fill the missing data following the numerical sequence in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a function to complete the sequence of hours in the following hash.

```
{
  name: "cardio", 
  data: [["06:00", 999], ["09:00", 154], ["10:00", 1059], ["11:00", 90]]
}
```

It should create all the missing values in the field data

```
["07:00", 0], ["08:00", 0], ["12:00", 0], ["13:00", 0] ... ["23:00", 0]
```

Expected result:

```
{
 name: "cardio", 
 data: [["06:00", 999], ["07:00", 0], ["08:00", 0], ["09:00", 154], ["10:00", 1059], ["11:00", 90]], ["12:00", 0], ["13:00", 0] ... ["23:00", 0]
}
```

Is it possible to do that? Something like:

```
data.each do |row|
 (6..23).each do |hour|
  .....
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of [`Array#assoc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-assoc) to do something like this:

> Searches through an array whose elements are also arrays comparing obj with the first element of each contained array using obj.==.

```
input = {
  name: "cardio",
  data: [["06:00", 999], ["09:00", 154], ["10:00", 1059], ["11:00", 90]]
}

input[:data] = 24.times.collect do |hour|
  hour = "%02d:00" % hour

  input[:data].assoc(hour) || [hour, 0]
end

puts input.inspect
# {:name=>"cardio", :data=>[["00:00", 0], ["01:00", 0], ["02:00", 0], ["03:00", 0], ["04:00", 0], ["05:00", 0], ["06:00", 999], ["07:00", 0], ["08:00", 0], ["09:00", 154], ["10:00", 1059], ["11:00", 90], ["12:00", 0], ["13:00", 0], ["14:00", 0], ["15:00", 0], ["16:00", 0], ["17:00", 0], ["18:00", 0], ["19:00", 0], ["20:00", 0], ["21:00", 0], ["22:00", 0], ["23:00", 0]]}
```

Answer (score 2):

*Data*

```
h = {name:"cardio", data:[["06:00", 999], ["09:00", 154], ["10:00", 1059], ["11:00", 90]]}
first =  7
last  = 23
```

*Code*

```
mdata = (first..last).each_with_object(h[:data].to_h) { |hour,g|
  g["%02d:00" % hour] ||= 0 }.sort
  #=> [["06:00", 999], ["07:00", 0], ["08:00", 0], ["09:00", 154], ["10:00", 1059],
  #    ["11:00", 90], ["12:00", 0],..., ["21:00", 0], ["23:00", 0]]
h.merge(h).merge(data: mdata)
  #=> {:name=>"cardio",
  #    :data=>[["06:00", 999], ["07:00", 0], ["08:00", 0], ["09:00", 154],
  #            ["10:00", 1059], ["11:00", 90], ["12:00", 0],...["23:00", 0]]
```